# I don't understand the Lyrics of Limp Bizkit new "Dad Vibes"

Tags: lyrics, metal

I don't understand at all why it goes in this song. Even a translator could not help. It looks like random words or some slang. I am not native speaker in English.

Can someone explain to me what the content of this song is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a self-parody. Limp Bizkit used to be a young band, now Fred Durst is old enough to be the dad of today's young generation. Here are a few of the specific lines:

> Check out your dad with the **swag** on the floor

Swag, short for swagger, it means cocky masculine confidence and style.

> Momma gon' brag when I walk in the door

No dad without a mom, right?

> Now everybody bounce with the franchise, come on

The "franchise" is Limp Bizkit, they used to be a scrappy, counterculture band, but now they're like a big old corporation. This is self-depreciating humor.

> Can't live with 'em, can't live without 'em

Everyone hates Limp Biskit, but they're still one of the biggest bands from their era to still be making music.

> New kid back on the block with a R.I.P

Fred is no longer "new", but he's also not dead. May also be a reference to New Kids on the Block, an 90s era white R&B boy band that received a lot of the same critical scorn as Limp Biskit.

> Dad got the sag in the back with a drip

Refers to how dads wear our pants, hanging off the butt, with sweat running down the crack.

> Come and get a sip

Do you want to drink it? Deliberately disgusting.

> **Flow** so **cold**, need **ice** to deliver

"Flow" is a term for the rhythm of a rap song. "Cold" is even cooler than cool (see "Hey Ya" for citation). (Vanilla) "Ice" was another non-respected 90s white rapper.

> Dad, don't stop (don't stop)

They're still making music, even though they are your dad's age.

> Y'all been gone for a minute (yup)

It's been a while since their last album.

Answer (score 1):

Even as a native speaker I'm struggling a little with this one (it uses some slang I'm not really familiar with), but overall the song's about being an ex-rockstar dad, the stereotype of a middle-aged/old man who "used to be cool" but has now settled down with a family. The general thrust of the song is that even though trends have changed, he's still cool ("drip", I think, is "fashionable clothing"). The lyrics are likely ironic: Limp Bizkit had a few years of popularity but were widely seen as a joke for the rest of their career; and "dad trying really hard to be cool" is itself a stereotype that people often joke about.

Answer (score 0):

sag with the drip. he's just talking about his Style. Note sure about any sort of sweat dripping thing but i could be wrong. seems like drip and swag are synonymous here...